# Overflow on badges in profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

[image: bug]

`text-overflow: ellipsis` doesn't work without `overflow: hidden`.

```
.profile-badges .badge-tag { overflow: hidden; }
```

(And some more text to meet quality standards. Isn't it funny that bug report with one-liner fix is too short to meet standards?)

Comment: "Isn't it funny that bug report with one-liner fix is too short to meet standards?" -> only if you refuse to reason about why such a limitation exists.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSE: [Badges with long names overflow on the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362466/289905).

Comment: I almost feel like a scientist that acquired priority on their patent.